# Can user properties be arrays in Google Analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have a website where one user can have many roles (e.g., "merchant", "customer", "admin"). These roles can be combined in any combination (e.g., users can be a "merchant" and a "customer"). Ideally, I'd like to filter analytics data by these roles.

Can I create a user property that's just an array of these roles?

```
firebase.analytics().setUserProperties({ roles: ['merchant', 'customer'] })
```

I realize that I could split this out into multiple properties…

```
firebase.analytics().setUserProperties({ isMerchant: true })
firebase.analytics().setUserProperties({ isCustomer: true })
firebase.analytics().setUserProperties({ isAdmin: false })
```

… but that would get messy as the number of roles grow. I'd prefer to use an array if possible.

#### Metadata

- Google Analytics 4
- Firebase 8.2.6

Comment: I have this same requirement. Did you find a workaround for attributing session-scoped arrays without proliferating the number of custom parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of property will be interpreted as a `string` not as an object or array.